# How to require a JS file from an external source/directory without path issues?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, path, require

How do I require another module from a different directory without having path issues?

For example,
`src/index.js`, has a `require('../other/main')` statement

Oh, there's an error, because in the `main.js` JS file, there are things like getting files from paths, and it's just a path issue. (e.g. `./SOMEFILE` won't work when it's clearly in that `other` directory path)

But, if I individually on my CLI, to `cd other`, and `npm start` (or `node main.js`), no path issue.

How do I `require` without having to `cd` into the directory to make the path work?

But I don't get it, how do I just easily require a JS file but from **another directory with a package.json** or whatever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `process.chdir(directory)` so you don't have path issues. https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processchdirdirectory

You can use `child_process.fork` to make a new process of your external JS script (so it runs).
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processforkmodulepath-args-options

We would have to use `process.chdir`, I cannot find another way.